# Showing that a function is bounded in $L^1$ given a bound on its distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $f \in L^2((0,T)\times\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a compact manifold.

Suppose I know that for every $k > 0$, 
$$\mu(\{|f| > k\}) \leq Mk^{-\frac 12}$$
for some constant $M$ (which is independent of $k$).

Does it follow that $$\int_0^T\int_\Omega |f| \leq C(M)$$
for some constant $C$ that depends on $M$?

---

I am wondering if some simple of seeing this if it is true at all. I am aware of the method using weak $L^p$ spaces (thanks to an answer on my previous thread) but that method is not easy to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $(0,T)\times\Omega$ work on $I=[0,1]$. Let 
\begin{align*}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
x^{-2} & x\in[1/n;1]\\
0 & x\in [0;1/n]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $|\{|f_n|>k\}|\leq |\{x^{-2}>k\}|=k^{-1/2}$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\infty$.

Comment: Your $f_n$ are not $L^2$. I made the same mistake. Basically, the inequality is not useful when $k$ is very large, because past a certain point it follows from being $L^2$.

Comment: Why not? They are bounded!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I mixed up your ranges, since you put the set closer to zero on the bottom, and since "blow up on a thin set" is a common trick for counterexamples. +1.